# Assetic dump files in the wrong place

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I'm trying to clean the way I manage my assets in one of my symfony 2 application, and I enhance weird issues.

I try to use "Named assets" as described here : [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets).
I find more simple to change a config file when you change your assets, than going into the template files.

So there is my yaml config for `assetic` :

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: "%kernel.debug%"
    filters:
        cssrewrite:
            apply_to: '\.css$|\.less$'
        lessphp:
            file:     '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php'
            apply_to: '\.less$'
        cssmin:
            file:     '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/natxet/CssMin/src/CssMin.php'
            apply_to: '\.css$|\.less$'
        jsmin:
            file:     '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/werkint/jsmin/JsMin/Minify.php'
            apply_to: '\.js$|\.twigjs$'

# ...

    font_awesome_css:
        inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less'
        output: 'dist/css/font-awesome.min.css'
```

And in my template, I refer to FontAwesome (I use FontAwesome as an example, problem occurs on my others css & javascript compiled from the yaml file) :

```
{% stylesheets '@font_awesome_css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

When I run `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod`, the file `web/dist/css/font-awesome.min.css` is correctly compiled and created, but I also have `web/css/f3c79b8.css` which was created.

And this is the second file which is used and seemingly the filters have not been applied on it.

If I add the filters explicitly in the yaml file :

```
font_awesome_css:
     inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less'
     output: 'dist/css/font-awesome.min.css'
     filters:
          - lessphp
          - cssmin
          - cssrewrite
```

It seems to produce a correct file (less has been compiled) but, as my font belongs to the `dist` folder, the css failed to load it.

So , How can I make my template to use the correct generated file `dist/css/font-awesome.min.css` and avoid the creation of files into `web/css` and `web/js` ?

I think there is something I have misunderstood about this feature.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you might need to use `assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` in this case.

Comment: @tftd : Thanks for the reply. I have tried and I obtain the same result with the `--no-debug` flag. As I'm in production environment, debug is already set to false in the assetic config.